# how many words end in certain character in function calling to different file?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a small function that takes the name of a file as an argument and returns how many WORDS in the file end in "!", "?" or ".".

So far I've tried the following:

```
def count_possible_sentences(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
    count = 0
    for ch in word_list:
        if ch in "!?.":
            count += 1
    return count
```

but this isn't working and is not counting how many individual WORDS end with those specified characters in the separate called file. I thought of splitting every word and looping through each character and if it contains one of the character it adds a +1 to the count but I am unsure of how to do that.

edit: also thought of just using .count? would that work? cheers

edit2:
here are my doctests I'm trying to make them pass:

```
def count_possible_sentences(file_name):
    """
    >>> count_possible_sentences("frances_oldham_kelsey.txt")
    45
    >>> count_possible_sentences("ernest_rutherford.txt")
    32
    >>> count_possible_sentences("marie_curie.txt")
    24
    """
```

and here is a link to the .txt that is failing:
https://pastebin.com/raw/1NYPeY29

it's saying expected: 45 got: 52

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
def count_possible_sentences(file_name):
    count = 0
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:              #Open file for read
        for line in wordfile:                      #Iterate each line
            for word in line.strip().split():      #Get words
                if word.endswith(("!", "?", ".")):  #Check if word ends with
                    count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: I didn’t know `str.endwith` accepts a tuple of suffixes to check! Excellent solution.

Answer (score 2):

The line...

```
if ch in '?!.':
```

...is not going to work as expected. You need to check each punctuation mark individually:

```
if any(ch.endswith(punc) for punc in '?!.'):
# or
if any(punc in ch for punc in '?!.'):
```

Comment: swapping it around to if '!?.' in ch: still doesn't work, returns 0 when i run it with doctests

Answer (score 2):

You can do this one line, if you prefer list comprehension. The `w[-1] in '!?.'` checks last character of a word.

```
def count_possible_sentences(file_name):
    return len([w for w in open(file_name).read().split() if w[-1] in '!?.'])

print(count_possible_sentences('input_file.txt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this using regex. I think this is what you want to do.

```py
import re
pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+(!|\?|\.)"
string = "This! sent contains? 3 of those! words !!"
a = len(re.findall(pattern, string))
print(a) # 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change if statement:

```
def count_possible_sentences(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as word_file:
        text_str = word_file.read()
        word_list = text_str.split()
    count = 0
    for item in word_list:
        if '!' in item or '?' in item or '.' in item:
             count += 1
    return count
```